# Flexbox : break into 2 columns when items increases more than 4

Tags: css, flexbox

I have multiple lists of items and when there is more than 4 in a list, I need it to break into a second column, but I can't quite figure out how. I need the flow/order to stay in column flow.

This is what I am trying to achieve using flexbox, but it's proving more difficult than I'm sure it should be. I am open to using css grid or anything else if it solves my problem:

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: Hi sorry about that. I will remember for next time.

Comment: I would use grid here  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dyobxGN ,** provide your HTML and CSS too to show your issue and attempts if you want your answer reopened and upvoted** .

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are trying, right. Add this style to the `ul`

```
ul {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-gap: 20px;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 20px;
    }
```

[This document explains all in detail](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-multicol-1/)

We also have a plugin to do the job [Check this](https://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)

```css
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
   
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem with `column-count: 3` is that I'm always then going to have 3 columns. For example, if I only had 7 items in my list, they will then spread over 3 columns. I need one column to have 4 items, then the rest spill into the next column, and so on.
So i need to break into another column, when that column hits 4 items.

Comment: @LeanneDickenson you can add `column-count` via jquery also. is this list item dynamic ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex box with `flex-direction: column;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` property. The main div should have a fixed height, so that the flex will wrap it children and create multiple column.

```css
#main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: start;
}

#main span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <span style="background-color:coral;">A</span>
  <span style="background-color:lightblue;">B</span>
  <span style="background-color:khaki;">C</span>
  <span style="background-color:pink;">D</span>
  <span style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</span>
  <span style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try the height on the container, but I really needed the container to be another height, maybe i'll have to add another container inside. Thanks

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer if it solves your problem.